# There is not such function in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f>0$, $f'>0$ and $f''<0$.

Tags: functions

Prove that there isn't a function $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$  such that
$f>0$, $f'>0$ and $f''<0$.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: So the domain has to be $x \in \mathbb{R}$? Can it be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Charlie: Being picky here, but $x=0$ gives 0, which means it is not strictly positive. Solution is simple, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is strictly concave and non-constant, either $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x)=-\infty$ or $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x)=-\infty$. In both cases, $f$ can't be always positive.

Comment: Also, because f strictly increasing both limits must exists.

Answer (score -1):

$f(x)= \sqrt{x}+1$ is perhaps a counter example. It is always positive, has a positive derivative and concave down.

Comment: The domain of f is real numbers.